# Is it possible to have different webhook on different branches in the same project?

Tags: github, webhooks

I wanted to know if it's possible to have different webhook on different branches in the same project with Github ?

I already have one but it's the easiest webhook in github with a configuration as :
"send me everything" on the master branche.

But I have a repository on github with 2 branches.
And I want to have 2 different webhook : one on each branches.

Is it possible to do that with github ?

If it's possible i haven't find how i can apply one webhook to one specific branche.

Comment: Are the webhooks going to the same URL? You can't have branch specific webhooks but can look for the branch in the event payload.

Comment: @osowskit : Yes webhook are going on the same URL (Jenkins url).
I will try to find how i can see what is in the event payload ! And then 
retrieve information i need to my project !

Thanks for your answer !

Comment: You may want to ask a new question on how to trigger Jenkins jobs via webhooks. This is similar if I understand your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108380/jenkins-how-to-build-a-specific-branch

Comment: Thank you, but i already have a webhook trigger and it works !