# How to use environment variables in a Jenkins pipeline job?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I posted this in the [Jenkins users Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/DcFy7dm52JU), but thought I'd post it here too.

I have a Jenkins Pipeline job, and in its Configuration page, I use a "Pipeline script from SCM" as my pipeline. One of this block's parameters is "Branch to build" of course. How can I used an environment variable for the text block? I tried, for example, $branchToBuild, ${branchToBuild} or "${branchToBuild}"  and it just takes those as literal values and does not interpolate the string. I do have that variable defined and use it in other jobs.

Someone suggested using ${env.branchToBuild}, so I tried env.branchToBuild, $env.branchToBuild, ${env.branchToBuild}, and "${env.branchToBuild}" all to NO avail, that is, they are also just taken as literal strings and not interpolated.

[image: Jenkins pipeline configuration]

Is it just not possible to do this?

Comment: Please put your code in your question.

Comment: There is NO code, it's just a text box in the Jenkins job configuration page. I edited the post to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **uncheck** *Lightweight checkout* **box** in order to use a `variable` as **Branch name** to build.

It's a [known Jenkins bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28447), here is more information : [How to pass project parameter as branch name to build in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46701461/how-to-pass-project-parameter-as-branch-name-to-build-in-jenkins)

> Apparently the code path is very different if you are using the
>   lightweight checkout, and that has not been resolved, apparently.

Another source : https://cleverbuilder.com/notes/jenkins-dynamic-git-branch/

Comment: Ding, ding, ding, ding... Thanks!