# DSL Seed Job for Multibranch pipeline with Bitbucket branch plugin suppress auto build of branches

Tags: jenkins, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

Have a DSL job to create multibranch pipeline jobs in jenkins, running Jenkins `2.107.1` with plugins: 'Branch API Plugin' `2.0.18`, 'Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin' `2.2.10`.

I'm unable to find a proper configuration function to enable property to "Suppress automatic SCM triggering", please help.

Here is my job that works but its just triggers the build as soon as it scans for branch:

```
multibranchPipelineJob("job") {
  configure {
    it / sources / data / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource' / source(class: 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMSource') {
      credentialsId('..')
      id("..")
      checkoutCredentialsId("..")
      repoOwner("owner")
      repository("my-repo")
      includes()
      excludes("PR-*")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how it works now... with the help of the following source code:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-branch-source-plugin

```
multibranchPipelineJob("job") {
  branchSources {
    branchSource {
      source {
        bitbucket {
          credentialsId("myid")
          repoOwner("iam")
          repository("job")                       
          traits {
            headWildcardFilter {
              includes("branchestoinclude")
              excludes("toexclude")
            }
          }
        }
      }
      strategy {
        defaultBranchPropertyStrategy {
          props {
            // keep only the last 8 builds
            buildRetentionBranchProperty {
              buildDiscarder {
                logRotator {
                  daysToKeepStr("-1")
                  numToKeepStr("8")
                  artifactDaysToKeepStr("-1")
                  artifactNumToKeepStr("-1")
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // Branch behaviour
  configure {
    def traits = it / sources / data / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource' / source / traits
    traits << 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BranchDiscoveryTrait' {
      strategyId(3) // detect all branches -refer the plugin source code for various options
    }
  }
  orphanedItemStrategy {
    discardOldItems {
      numToKeep(8)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where is suppress scm here

Comment: that was not need on my case because, i would beed to trigger build when i commit changes, i would need to trigger build. If you know the behaviour of SCM triggering you can very well use it.. but I am not sure, however you can check the blog https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291748/adding-suppress-automatic-scm-triggering-except-for-named-branches-in-jenkins-jo

Comment: I coped the answer into https://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/ and got this error:
javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptException: (script, line 3) No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.workflow.BranchSourcesContext.branchSource()

Comment: I ran the DSL job in Jenkins and it worked - not sure why job-dsl.herokuapp threw an error