# How to update a Windows machine with changes done in a git repository

Tags: windows, git, powershell, shell, jenkins

I am planning to do below

Copy from git repository to a Windows machine each time a commit/ update is made to that folder only. May be something like Jenkins can be used for same but unable to determine how can I do it?

1. Check commit made to repo ( this I have done)
2. As soon as commit is made to repo, trigger a jenkins job that will update this change to a windows server ( How to do this?)

Answer (score 0):

If the repository is local, it would be easier to push directly to the Windows machine, assuming it has an SSH server (which [Windows 10 2019.09 and more now have](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview))

If the repository is distant, you can configure a webhook in order to call a Jenkins server for a specific job.
See for instance "[Triggering a Jenkins build every time changes are pushed to a Git branch on GitHub](https://oncomputingwell.princeton.edu/2018/01/triggering-a-jenkins-build-every-time-changes-are-pushed-to-a-git-branch-on-github/)" by [David Luet](https://geosciences.princeton.edu/people/david-j-luet)

Or you can [define a Jenkins pipeline that GitLab-CI can execute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52043890/6309).

In both cases, your Jenkins job will have to copy the checked out repository.
I would use [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) to compress the repository into one file (or a simple tar), copy it over the Windows server, and decompress there.

Comment: hey Thanks, I am done until pipeline but the query was actually how to copy the checked out repo to Win machine

Comment: @AskQues If the Win machine is a Jenkins agent, your pipeline can bundle the checkoed out repo (done by Jenkins in its dedicated workspace), copy the bundle to the target folder, and clone/pull from it