# dynamically replace branch name in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to Jenkins, and stuck at replacing branch name in Jenkinsfile from Jenkins.

I want to write a common Jenkinsfile, and in that I want to pick branch name from Jenkins. Below is the snippet from my Jenkinsfile

> checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']],

Whatever the branch name I select from Jenkins, it should replace the same in Jenkinsfile and do the build.

I have gone through the answers 
[parametrized build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108380/jenkins-how-to-build-a-specific-branch)

Somewhat not able to do the same.
Can anyone refer me to the doc/link which I can go through and implement the same?

My Changes:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'params.Branch_Select']],
```

enter image description here

[image: GIT PARAMETER]

[image: BRANCH SPECIFIER]

[image: Jenkinsfile]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the above question. UNCHECK the box.

[image: Lightbox]

Answer (score 0):

In your Jenkinsfile, add a parameters section which will accept BRANCH_NAME as parameter

```
parameters {
        string(defaultValue: "master", description: 'enter the branch name to use', name: 'BRANCH_NAME')
    }
```

and use that variable in your checkout step as follows:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "*/${BRANCH_NAME}"]]])
```

Note: You have to run the build once to see the 'Build with parameters' option.

Sample pipeline with just a checkout stage:

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(defaultValue: "develop", description: 'enter the branch name to use', name: 'BRANCH_NAME')
    }
    stages{
        stage('Checkout'){
            steps{
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "*/${BRANCH_NAME}"]], gitTool: 'jgit', userRemoteConfigs: [[url: "https://github.com/githubtraining/hellogitworld.git"]]])
                //checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "*/${BRANCH_NAME}"]],url:'https://github.com/brianmyers/hello'])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not able to read my Jenkins file. Not able to find git repo

Comment: I added sample pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your help