# Can I configure Jenkins to only test PRs against a particular branch?

Tags: git, jenkins, github, continuous-integration, integration-testing

Basically, I have some slow tests and some fast tests, and three branches, `dev` `staging` and `production`. There are tons of PRs against `dev`, but only a weekly PR against `staging`. I'd only like to run the slow test suite when I make a PR against `staging`, to ensure nothing broken ever goes into `staging`. Is there a way to tell Jenkins "Run this test job for PRs against `staging`?"

Comment: Would this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108380/jenkins-how-to-build-a-specific-branch

Comment: Not quite. I don't know what name GitHub will assign my PR branch. It'll just be something like PR-1783 or whatever number I'm up to.

Comment: Are you using scripted / declarative pipeline?

Comment: Scripted, could do either or though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. There is a Jenkins environment variable named `CHANGE_TARGET` which contains the name of the branch you're making a PR against. This can be accessed by writing `${env.CHANGE_TARGET}`.